# Get segments from AVPlayerItemTrack

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer, segments

I am trying to work with a m3u8 playlist in an AVPlayer. I get the playlist through the web and I want to get the segments that each video track has or the current segment of the video.

I am using the apple example code in order to do this.

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.158/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];

AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

NSString *tracksKey = @"tracks";

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:tracksKey] completionHandler:
     ^{

      }
```

I have a AVPlayerItemTrack which I get it from AVPlayerItem I use for displaying the video but I can't find a way to get the segments for this track.

Any ideas?

Comment: I may add some comments, maybe my question was not so clear. The segments are the .ts files that I create from a video. So I have a m3u8 playlist which contains lots of .ts files. The thing I want to do is to get which .ts file is currently visible in the video player that plays the playlist!

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?